# Link a git repository under one GitHub organization to another

Tags: git, github

The scenario is:

I work for a company with an associated GitHub organization, called *org-a*. Often when we do work for clients, we work in repositories under the client's own associated GitHub organization, called *org-b*.

I would like to somehow "link" the repositories we work on, under *org-b*, so they show up on *org-a*'s GitHub profile. That way people can better see what my company works on etc.

How can this be accomplished?

Now, I know about submodules, but don't know if it possible to add a submodule to an GitHub organization/profile, without adding it to an existing repository.

Also, I have thought about the possibility of forking the *org-b* repository to *org-a*. The problem here is redundancy and that the forked repository would have to be manually updated when something is committed to the original repository.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: How about https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Comment: Wow, did not know about that mirror feature. Guess this could be configured with a hook, so that it automatically updated the mirror. Thanks for that golden information!